# Is that possible to open NSImage with Photoshop in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

Is that possible to open NSImage with Photoshop in Cocoa?
And how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following (with Objective-C method hints).

1. **Find a temporary folder**

   Use `-[NSFileManager URLForDirectory: inDomain: appropriateForURL: url create: error:]`

   (Or the Desktop folder while testing)
2. **Save the NSImage as a file in the temporary folder**

   (Use `NSUUID` to get a random file name)

   Get the `NSBitmapImageRep` from the `NSImage`

   Convert the `NSBitmapImageRep` to `NSData`

   Use `-[NSData writeToURL: atomically:]`
3. **Open the file in Photoshop**

   Use `-[NSWorkspace openFile: withApplication:]`